# Disallowing two Jenkins projects to build simultaneously

Tags: jenkins

I have two projects in Jenkins that are not linked to each other in any way (database build, and application build/test build). The two may never build at the same time in Jenkins, because tests access the database and it may not be building while tests run on the other build. Is it possible to make sure that the two projects never build at the same time? Apparently it is possible to do this for child/parent builds, but these two have no formal relation to each other. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're looking for a load balancing solution, such as [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scoring+Load+Balancer+plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin).  If you use that plugin, then create a category and assign both jobs that category, you can be assured that the two jobs will never build at the same time.